# Datagrid unexpectedly showing textbox for readonly cell

Tags: c#, asp.net, datagridview

I am adding new webforms to an asp.net project that I did 14 years ago. Originally developed in VS2003, .NetFramework 1.1.  I have adapted the project to VS2017, .NetFramework 4.5 and all is working fine except this minor bug that I would like to get rid of.

[image: Screen capture]

I have a datagridview that works perfectly on two pages but the third, which I just added, behaves differently. After having clicked "edit" (buttons [01-02]...) and while the row is in edit-mode and I click an edit-button on a different row the datagridview should only refresh and not do anything and I am able to continue editing the fields but now the datagridview refreshes and gives me a textbox in a read-only field. I can still continue editing the data and save successfully when clicking again on the [01-02] button.

I have made sure that the dataset used has this column set to read-only. The datagridview has this column set to read-only.

This behavior started after I changed the data-worker-layer-class and changed how data is populated from the database by copy-ing the dataset to a temporary dataset which is adjusted to the data to be presented to the user and returning that temporary dataset to the code-behind of the webform. I have set the sum column to be read-only.

Some things I do know about this old web that I am working with:

- Controls on the webform are not contained within a PlaceHolder as it was troublesome in VS2003
- Some RegisterStartupScripts that set focus to the first input field are obsolete but they still work on the other pages but I have fixed that in this new webpage
- The event handler on_click is tweaked to use one button for starting editing and saving the data and to have nothing happening if a user clicks on the other row in the datagrid.

I would really like to avoid to create a new solution and re-coding...

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please visit https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and read up on how to post a good question. Please add relevant code to your question, and insert the picture into the question. A question should be complete as is, and should not rely on external images or code. Please illustrate where in the code things go wrong, and show us what you have done to debug your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Solved. First of all the grid I am using is DataGrid (.net 1.1) not DataGridView. Sorry for the mixup.

After databinding I did this:

```
private void fillTheDataGrid()
{
     DataSet dsData = this.getDataForMyGrid(...); //fetches data from the data-worker-class
     dgMyGrid.DataSource = dsData;
     dgMyGrid.DataBind();
     ((BoundColumn)dgMyGrid.Columns[10]).ReadOnly = true; // (Added this and it worked)
}
```